# How to query the first row efficiently?

Tags: kdb

I have a table with large amount of records:

```
date          instrument    price
2019.03.07    X             1.1
2019.03.07    X             1.0
2019.03.07    X             1.2
...
```

When I query for the day opening price, I use:

```
1 sublist select from prices where date = 2019.03.07, instrument = `X
```

It takes a long time to execute because it selects all the prices on that day and get the first one.

I also tried:

```
select from prices where date = 2019.03.07, instrument = `X, i = 0        //It does not return any record (why?)
select from prices where date = 2019.03.07, instrument = `X, i = first i  //Seem to work. Does it?
```

In Oracle an equivalent will be:

```
select * from prices where date = to_date(...) and instrument = "X" and rownum = 1
```

and Oracle will stop immediately when it finds the first record.

How to do this in KDB (e.g. stop immediately after it finds the first record)?

Comment: Using `i=0` would only work if the instrument you are looking for is the first item in your table. With `i=first i` the query will use the first index in your filtered selection.

Comment: Have you added (or considered adding) an attribute to your instrument column? If you were to apply the `p# attribute, for example, it should make the second clause in your select statement (instrument=X) significantly faster.

Answer (score 3):

In kdb, `where` subclauses in `select` statements are executed sequentially. i.e. only those records which pass the first "test" get passed to the second test. With that in mind, looking at your two attempts:

```
select from prices where date = 2019.03.07, instrument = `X, i = 0        //It does not return any record (why?)
```

This doesn't (necessarily) return anything, because by the time it gets to the `i=0` check, you've already filtered out some records (possibly including the first record in the original table, which would have `i=0`)

```
select from prices where date = 2019.03.07, instrument = `X, i = first i  //Seem to work. Does it?
```

This one should work. First you filter by date. Then within the records for that date, you select the records for instrument `` `X ``. Then *within* those records, you take the record where `i` is the `first i` (where `i` has already been filtered down, so `first i` is simply the index of the first record [still the index from the original table, not the filtered down version])

Comment: Further to this if your intention is to get the opening price for all instruments you might want to try `select from prices where date=2019.03.07,i=(first;i)fby instrument`.

Comment: I just did a simple measure using `\t`. The versions of `1 sublist` and `i = first i` takes the same time to complete. How can I achieve something like `rownum=1` in Oracle?

Comment: The [? (find)](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/search/#find) operator can find the index of the first instance of your instrument, then match that to the `i` column. Something like:
`select from prices where date=2019.03.07, i=instrument?\`X`

Comment: @JorgeSawyer That is great way! Do you want to make it an answer?

Comment: @texasbruce if you look at the comments on Rahul's answer, you can see that this solution proposed by Jorge doesn't actually work unfortunately

Comment: It works in my case because instrument is not sorted, which I apologize I should have mentioned before. It is our log table which we don't want to sort because of performance.

Answer (score 0):

Q-SQL equivalent for that is [select[n]](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/9_Queries_q-sql/#9324-select) which also performs better than other approaches in most of the cases. Positive 'n' will give first n records and negative will give last n records.

```
q) select[1] from prices where date = 2019.03.07, instrument = `X
```

There is no inbuilt functionality to stop after first match. You can write custom function for that but that would probably execute slower than above supported version.

Comment: The find operator finds only the first match to a vector, so we could use that to get this functionality: `select from prices where date=2019.03.07, i=instrument?\`X`

Comment: This will not work and will give an unpredictable answer. Reason for that is after the first filter, ''i' may not start from 0 but find in the second filter will generate an index with 0 as the base. The second filter(find) cannot keep track of indexes generated by from the first filter

Comment: We could fix this as:  `select from prices where date=2019.03.08,i=i instrument?\`X` . But as find operator does not consider attributes like sorted attribute, it would run slower on big tables with proper attributes compared to other inbuilt searching. On normal tables it could run faster.

Comment: I had thought that the `i` column would start from zero within any given partition. Are there any particular scenarios where my assumption fails, or is the behavior of the `i` column generally unpredictable?

Comment: You are correct that `i` starts from 0 for a partition. For partitioned database it will work fine but for memory table it will not.  Also, in case of partitioned database if an extra filter gets added in between date and instrument filter than it will again become the same situation where `i` will not start from 0 and will depend on last filter.